# Can anyone recommend a free website builder?

Tags: marketing

We are in the process of creating content to go on a website we are building to promote the launch of our book. We wondered if anyone can recommend any free website builders that host the website for free or for a small charge. It would be preferred if the website was mobile compatible too. Thanks.

Comment: How does this question pertain to writing?

Comment: Well apologies for not making myself clear, reading back it does come accross as a broad question. I have only been using the site for a few days so im just getting into the swing of things. We are building a website as an information recource for readers, writers or even publishers to get to know more about us should they wish to. But we also have a few marketing ideas for our first novel involving the use of a website, but with respect we would rather not share all of our plans. But I take the point and in future I will endeavor to state the premise of the question before asking.

Comment: @KDNovels - No worries, but whether this is on or off-topic is [currently being discussed in meta](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/743/scope-of-questions-about-marketing). You may be able to help keep this open by editing it to make it more specific to building a website for a book, as opposed to building a website for anything at all.

Comment: Website builders can certainly be helpful to writers, but this question would be equally appropriate to _anybody_ needing a promotional website. In addition, I'm afraid recommendation questions ("Please recommend me a...") and list questions ("What are all the links you can give me about...") [do not work well in the Stack Exchange format](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). I'm afraid I need to close this, at least pending the Meta discussion, (cont.)

Comment: but I hope if you have any questions unique to the writing and publishing fields, you'll be able to ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are some websites for free website builders :

1) http://www.wix.com/

2) http://www.ucoz.com/

3) http://www.webs.com/

4) http://www.webnode.in/

5) http://www.350.com/

Comment: Wow thanks, I have been trying out Wix and it appears to have a lot of free content and also has a mobile compatible option. Thanks for the input.

Comment: It's my pleasure that my answer is of great help to you.

Answer (score 2):

I would say Wordpress is the simplest to use. It is free, but with some limitations on what you can change. You also get 'wordpress' in the url. If that is not a problem, I would recommend it.

Comment: Does wordpress provide option for mobile compatibility?

Comment: What doesn't Wordpress provide options for. Just select a theme that is customed for mobile devices.